# How to display the users post to the user in the html form?

Tags: html, django

I have made a page where when the user logs in they can see their own posts but no posts are showing?

I have created an HTML and added the ginja tags representing the data in my post model but for some reason, it doesn't display my logged in users posts, only the empty HTML.

Here is my HTML file for users to view their own posts:

```html
{% extends '../base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if post_list %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
        <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
        <p class="card-text ">{{ object.content | safe }}</p>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Views File

```html
class PostListbyAuthorView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_list_by_author.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.kwargs['pk']
        target_author = get_object_or_404(PostAuthor, pk=id)
        return Post.objects.filter(author=target_author)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListbyAuthorView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post'] = get_object_or_404(PostAuthor, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context


class IndexPage(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'blog/all_posts.html'


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

Models file

```html
class PostAuthor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter your bio details here.")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["user", "bio"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-by-author', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(PostAuthor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I think your template might be a little bit off, if you try:
`{% for post in object_list %}<p>{{post.title}}</p>{% endfor %}`, do you get anything rendered?

Comment: That was all it was! Thanks :)